# Importing `File Should Exist` Keyword from multiple libraries

Tags: robotframework

Robot Framework provides the `File Should Exist` Keyword in both `OperatingSystem` and `SSHLibrary`. This is true for some other Keywords as well but just taking this as an example.
My question is how do I tell my test case which Keyword I am intending to use?

I believe `File Should Exist` from `OperatingSystem` works on the local file system (where the TC is being run) and the `File Should Exist` from `SSHLibrary` works on the remote server file system. Or am I wrong here too?

Comment: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#handling-keywords-with-same-names

Answer (score 2):

You can use both keywords by prefixing the library's name to the keyword.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Sample Test
    SSHLibrary.File Should Exit    ${args}
    OperatingSystem.File Should Exist    ${args}
```

You'll find more about handling keywords with the same name in the [user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#handling-keywords-with-same-names).

Answer (score 0):

You are right. File Should Exist from OperatingSystem works on the local file system (where the TC is being run) and the File Should Exist from SSHLibrary works on the remote server file system.

But you are connecting to a remote system from local. After connecting to remote if you want to do some operation on local you can by using the OperatingSystem library keywords.

So, when you have keywords with the same name in different libraries use the library name as prefix.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Sample Test
    SSHLibrary.File Should Exit    ${args}
    SSHLibrary.Get File  <filename>
    OperatingSystem.File Should Exist    ${args}
```

In the above case even though  you connected to remote system, still you can do operations on local system.